# How to check for gameObject while Grid Snaping in Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, grid, drag, snapping

I am trying to make a game which allows moving objects by snapping them on the grid, I already figured out to snape them to grid but there is one thing little problem, I want to check if there is already a game object placed on that same grid so that I won't let the dragging game object snap to that same spot but the thing is that I have a different game object shapes.

see for yourself

[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK7DW.png)

how can I achieve that?

Comment: Do the game objects have colliders attached? If they do you could always use [Physics2D.BoxcastAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.BoxCast.html) at the snap to vector and check if there are any hits. If they do have colliders attached I can give an example.

Comment: thank u for the reply, Yes I have colliders attached and yes giving me an example would be more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're on a square grid I think the best way to do this is with [Physics2D.Boxcast()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.BoxCast.html). Basically what you're doing is casting a box at the snap vector before moving the game object.

So in your code before you move the game object to the snap location:

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.BoxCast(snapTo, boxSize, 0.0f, Vector2.zero);
if (hit == null)
{
    // We're clear to move
}
else
{
    // Something is in the way
}
```

Where `snapTo` is the `Vector2` of the location you're going to snap to and `boxSize` is a `Vector2` equal to the size of one grid position (you might need to play around with this a bit). The last two arguments, `0.0f` refers to the angle of the box, which we don't need so just set it to zero and `Vector2.zero` is the direction of the cast, but we're casting in one spot so this also doesn't matter.

I'm assuming that only one game object can occupy the space at once, so there will only ever be one hit. If there's a chance for more than one you can change it to `RaycastHit2D[] hits` and `Physics2D.BoxCastAll` then check if `hits.Length` is greater than 0.

Comment: Thank u so very much, everything is clear now, I was just missing Physics2D.Boxcast(), I never thought I would use it hhh, anyway thank u a lot u were such a great help

Answer (score 0):

I had some troubles with **Physics2D.Boxcast()** , so instead i used **Physics2D.OverlapBox()** and it is working just fine.

```
isColl = Physics2D.OverlapBox(ObjectToMove.position, size, 0f, layerM);
                if (isColl == true)
                {
                    // Something is in the way
                }
                else
                {
                    //Clear to go
                }
```